# Conversion of Elasticsearch normal query to BoolQuery is not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to make a query to search documents with ID = "CASE_CREATE_DATE#10000078". If i am using below query then it is working.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "EVENTS.ID" : "CASE_CREATE_DATE#10000078"
        }
    }
}
```

but when i am using same query with bool then it is not working.

Bool Query i am using:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "EVENTS.ID": {
              "value": "CASE_CREATE_DATE#10000078",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me what is wrong with my bool query.

Answer (score 0):

You're not searching for the same value (`CASE_CREATE_DATE#10000078` vs `true`) and you're using `term` instead of `match`

The following query will work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "EVENTS.ID": {
              "value": "CASE_CREATE_DATE#10000078",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```